# Why has my post on SuperUser been copied to onooks.com?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about an issue with Cisco Webex desktop application.

[Issue with Cisco Webex](https://superuser.com/questions/1539563/issue-with-cisco-webex)

When I was doing further research I found that within a short amount of time the question had been copied here:

https://www.onooks.com/issue-with-cisco-webex/

What's going on?

I can't find any reference to 'onooks' on superuser.

Comment: It has absolutely no connection to Super User.  Your question was scrapped by a random website

Comment: @Ramhound No so. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/267099

Comment: Mine question was SCRAPED by Onooks *in only a minute* after I've asked it...

Comment: Wow that scraper is really bad, t onlhey copied the question, no answers, in a wordpress post, with the tags mapped to the description

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### What is a "scraper" and why is that bad?

> Historically, SCRAPER here on Stack Exchange meant "Stack Content
>   Republishers Attributing Poorly and/or Excelling at Ranking." More
>   generally, a scraper is another website which copies content from our
>   sites either by scraping directly from our pages, accessing the
>   information through our API, or some other means. In principle,
>   there's actually nothing wrong with doing this. Our content is
>   licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0 and is freely
>   redistribituble, so long as they follow the attribution requirements
>   and link back to us as the source. Some sites, however, do not follow
>   these rules or bring up other concerns in the process.
>
> ...
>
> **How do I go about reporting these sites?**
>
> Please [contact us](https://meta.superuser.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select the
>   "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"
>   option from the drop-down, and provide as much information as
>   possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that is scraping
>   many questions, please provide an example of a question on their site
>   and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any Google
>   search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any other
>   information you might have can be included in the free-form text box.

Source [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/267099)

onooks.com has been scraping SuperUser and many other SE sites without attribution. I have reported it to SE via the contact us link

Answer (score 5):

Take any SE question, google the title in quotes, and see the plethora of scrapers out there.  For example my highest scoring question was

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/how-do-i-open-a-master-link-in-a-chain

which shows up 12 times, frequently translated too.   Here's an example in Korean https://qastack.kr/bicycles/45958/how-do-i-open-a-master-link-in-a-chain and this outfit seems to do Russian, German, French, Thai, Chinese, Indonesian, etc.  And again, no attribution except leaving user-profile links in place.